# dynamically created elements from angular are not responding to events

Tags: jquery

I'm adding elements to my screen using angularjs and originally because the .live is depreciated in jQuery I was doing the following:

```
    var CHECK_INTERVAL = 100; //100 = 1/10th second, choose appropriate 
    function checkForElement() {
        $('input[type=checkbox]').each(function (index) {
            $(this).bootstrapSwitch();
            $('input[id^="chk"]').on('switchChange.bootstrapSwitch', function (event, state) {
                //alert('got here!');
            });
        });
        setTimeout(checkForElement, CHECK_INTERVAL);
    }
    setTimeout(checkForElement, CHECK_INTERVAL);
```

Everything was working pretty good until I had to use the new elements that displayed after the initial page load.

I have the following code that manipulates another section of code:

```
        $('input[id^="chk"]').on('switchChange.bootstrapSwitch', function (event, state) {...
```

However, the new elements that get created after the page load do not see this code.

What can I do to allow the newly created elements to see the code above that checks to see if the checkbox is clicked?

Comment: From The docs: Event handlers are bound only to the currently selected elements; they must exist at the time your code makes the call to .on() - in other words use an existing element (like document) and delegate to your input field.

Comment: get in the habit of using directives to bind such events

Comment: @charlietfl do you have a good example of how to do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll have to use:

```
$(document).on(event, element, function() {});
```

On your case:

```
$(document).on('switchChange.bootstrapSwitch', 'input[id^="chk"]', function (event, state) { ... }
```